# How to execute "./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies" from gradle plugin

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to write my own gradle plugin in Kotlin. It executes fine, but I want the `build` task to be run with `--refresh-dependencies` argument, such that the final outcome is the equivalent of

```
./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies
./gradlew publishToMavenLocal
```

Here is my custom plugin:

```
class PublishManager : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(target: Project) {
        target.task("syncAndPublish") {
            doLast {}
        }.dependsOn("publishToMavenLocal")
         .dependsOn("build") // HOW TO ADD -refresh-dependencies HERE?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your plugin:

```
target.gradle.beforeProject {
    gradle.startParameter.isRefreshDependencies = true
}
```